# disabling a button on form 2 from form 1 with a checkbox

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I have two form objects: `form1` and `form2`.

I have 1 button on `form2` and a check box on `form1`. When the check box is checked, I want to show the button and when it is unchecked I want the button to be disabled. I know that in visual basic I did such a thing like this:

```
form2.button.visible = false
```

How would I do something like this in c# ?

Comment: It's basically the same in C#.  You get a reference to the form and then you access the appropriate member.  In VB, fields generated by the designer for controls are `Friend` by default while they are `private` by default in C#.  If you want them to be accessible from the outside then declare them as `internal`, which is equivalent to `Friend`.  I'd sooner use a `public` method in both languages but that's up to you.  The difference is that there's no default instance in C#.  That means that you need to keep a reference to the form when you create it, i.e. assign it to a field.

Comment: why not put it as an answer @jmcilhinney

Comment: can you possibly provide some code please. I have been searching fir the answer for a while now..

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox, see the comment from Thisguydontknow after yours?  That's why I posted a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *general case* (when `Form1` and `From2` instances are independent) you can do something like that. In `Form2` implement a *public property*:

```
  public partial class Form2 {
    ...
    public Boolean IsMyButtonVisible {
      get {
        return myButton.Visible;
      } 
      set {
         myButton.Visible = value; 
      } 
    } 
    ...
  }
```

In `Form1` on `myCheckBox` `CheckedChanged` find out `Form2` instances and *assign the property*:

```
  public partial class Form1 {
    ...
    private void myCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      foreach(Form f in Application.OpenForms) {
        Form2 form2 = f as Form2; 

        if (form2 != null)
          form2.IsMyButtonVisible = myCheckBox.Checked;
      }
    }
    ...
  }
```