# How do I disable a Checkbox Control in Form1 from Form2 by checking a Checkbox Control

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

What I want to do is :

Disable Checkbox Control (Name : **Checkbox1**) placed in **Form1** by checking another Checkbox Control in another form (**Form2**)

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Communicating between forms is the same principle regardless of what data you're communicating so you can research, attempt and post back when you have an actual issue.

Comment: Please read this question, it's same concept: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479548/disabling-a-button-on-form-2-from-form-1-with-a-checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it as follows:

1. Define a new boolean setting (e.g., `myFlag`) in your application settings (if you do not know how to do it, please leave a comment below this answer and I'll guide you how to do that)
2. In the properties window of `Checkbox1`, under the `(Application Settings)` section, bind the `Enabled` property of this checkbox to `myFlag` (again, let me know if you need more help on this step)
3. Double click on the second checkbox in Form2 (I've assumed that its name is `ch2`) to write the `CheckedChanged` handler of this checkbox as follows:

```
    Private Sub ch2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ch2.CheckedChanged

        My.Settings.flag = Not ch2.Checked

    End Sub
```

Finished!

Please leave comments if you have any question on each step.

**Details on Step 2: Binding a Property**

1. Click on `CheckBox1` to select it and the press `F4` to open the `Properties` window.
2. Click the `+` sign beside the `(Application Settings)` row to expand it as follows:
   [image]
3. Select the `PropertyBinding` to open the ```Application Settings for 'CheckBox1'" window:
   [image]
4. Scroll down to reach to the `Enabled` property and then open its dropdown list and select `myFlga` which you've defined in your application:
   [image]

Done!

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do i bind the Enabled property of the checkbox to myFlag?

Comment: I explained for you in details in my answer. Please see the **Details on Step 2: Binding a Property** section in my answer. Please feel free to ask any more questions about the steps.

Comment: You're welcome! Please check mark this answer to accept it as a solution if it worked for you. Thanks!